# Count files number without repeat the comment of the print for each file

Tags: python

I want show how many files I have in my directory, but without repeating my print comment.

```
while True:

    if correct_path.upper() == "Y":

        # List all files/folders of the directory
        files = os.listdir(current_path)

        # Show each file of the directory
        for file in files:
            files_count += 1
            print(f"\n{files_count}. {file}")
        print(f"You have {files_count} files in your directory.")
        return
```

I mean, I want show first how many files I have and after that my files with his respective number.

Comment: Well, does code that you put in a loop happen multiple times, or just once? How many times do you want the `print` to occur? Therefore, where should it go?

Comment: Yes, I have another conditions after that part of the code. This part print(f"You have {files_count} files in your directory.") only once with sum of all files. But this print(f"\n{files_count}. {file}") for each file in the directory

Comment: Right. Now, *why* does it print that "for each file in the directory"? Could it be because you have put it inside the `for file in files` loop? Do you *want* it to print repeatedly? Therefore, *should* it be in that loop? What happens if you take it outside of that loop? Does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:

    if correct_path.upper() == "Y":

        # List all files/folders of the directory
        files = os.listdir(current_path)

        # Show each file of the directory
        fileIndex = {}
        for file in files:
            files_count += 1
            fileIndex[file] = files_count
        print(f"You have {files_count} files in your directory.")
        for k,v in fileIndex.items():
            print("{} - {}".format(v, k))
        return
```

Basically, you are printing in a for loop, so it will be printed on every iteration. To avoid that, you will have to move your print statement outside.
Inorder to print the file name and its number, you need to store it somewhere.
For that purpose, I am storing it in a dictionary in this format:

> {filename1: 1, filename2: 2} and so on for rest of the files.

Then, iterate the dictionary and print the index and file name corresponding to it.

Comment: Thanks! I try with another for loop, but that's not what I wanted but I see it's the only way